# Weird screenshot appears in camera roll

Tags: ios, camera-roll

So I recently found a photo of what appears to be a screenshot of a blend of iOS and macOS in my camera roll. It says it was taken on the 1st of September, but I am 100% sure it wasn't there then. I didn't take it, I'm sure of that as well. It seems to have Vietnamese text (I'm not in Vietnam) and I just don't know what to make of it.[image: weird screenshot]

I have been messing around with some emulator profiles, if that's any help.

What I'd like to know is, how did this get in my photos, and what is the screenshot of?

Comment: As far as I am aware, emulator profiles don't simply change stuff like photos. Chances are you gave access to an app that seemed alright but then added that photo. Maybe check your Privacy Settings and see which apps can access your Photos.